# Retrieve multiple values local storage and show within div element

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to show the keys and their values for all the data in local storage.

I have written some HTML And javascript:

```js
// Setting some values in the local storage
  localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
  localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Orange");
  localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Green");
  localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Pink");


// Attempt to retrieve them

  function allStorage() {

    var archive = [],
        keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
        i = 0, key;

    for (; key = keys[i]; i++) {
        archive.push( key + '=' + localStorage.getItem(key));
    }

  document.getElementbyId("result").innerHTML = archive;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>


<button onclick="allStorage()">Show Local Storage</button>
```

Does anyone know where I might be going wrong here?

From what I can see: The variables are being set correctly as they're accessible in the console. When I click to run the function though, nothing happens in the window or the console.

The result I'm looking for is:

```
lastnameSmithlastnameOrangelastnameGreenlastnamePink
```

to be set withing `<div id="result">`

Comment: localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith"); localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Orange"); - you are overriding the values, key name should be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues.
You have a typo in your code (Capitalize the b in getElementById)

Second, you are overwriting the key "lastname" over and over again.
so the first line 
  localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
sets the key of lastname to "Smith",
Then the very next line you are overwriting that value with "Orange", then "Green", and finally "Pink"... So when you click the button, the value stored in the "lastname" key is "Pink".  This result in the div tag only showing "lastname=Pink"

If your desire is to store all the last names into local storage for later keeping, then put them into an array and store the array.
Then when you want the lastnames you can retrieve the one key and show all the possible values. 
Here is your code modified a bit to produce the results you requested in your original post.

```
// Setting some lastname values in the local storage
localStorage.setItem("lastname", ["Smith", "Orange", "Green", "Pink"]);

// Attempt to retrieve them
function allStorage() {
    var archive = [];
    var key = "lastname";
    var lastNameValues= localStorage.getItem(key).split(",");
    lastNameValues.forEach(function(item){
        archive.push(key +"="+ item)
    });

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = archive;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one and key names for `localStorage` should unique  otherwise it will override the values.

HTML

```
  <div id="result"></div>
  <button onclick="allStorage()">Show Local Storage</button>
```

JS

```
 // Setting some values in the local storage
      localStorage.setItem("lastname1", "Smith");
      localStorage.setItem("lastname2", "Orange");
      localStorage.setItem("lastname3", "Green");
      localStorage.setItem("lastname4", "Pink");


    // Attempt to retrieve them

      function allStorage() {

        var archive = [],
            keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
            i = 0, key;

        for (; key = keys[i]; i++) {
            archive.push( key + '=' + localStorage.getItem(key));
        }

         document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = archive;
    }
```